# .org file sync with notion.so

Tags: org-mode

I came across [notion.so](https://www.notion.so) and a couple of friends are using it in their firm. I was wondering if someone tried to make the todo in notion work with .org? The web wasn't really helpful in finding any solution out there

Answer (score 5):

As of yet, the folks at Notion have not released a web API (as far as I know). I've been using Notion extensively since June 2018. There's a [reverse-engineered API on Github](https://github.com/kjk/notionapi) (described [here](https://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/88aee8f43620471aa9dbcad28368174c/how-i-reverse-engineered-notion-api.html)) that might be helpful in the meantime.

Comment: notion recently [release an api](https://developers.notion.com/)